# Forwarded call to "operator new()" in IDA Pro

Tags: ida

I'm using `IDA Pro` with the Hexrays decompiler.

There is a function like this:

[image: Function 1]

That function assigns the result of `sub_100033AE` to `dword_10005368`. So to know what the `DWORD` is, I checked what does that `sub_100033AE` do, but surprise...

[image: Function 2]

Its assembly is:

[image]

What I am wondering is: how is it just returning a call to `new()`? What is its purpose? What does it return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the decompiler failed to recognize a register argument to `new()`. `new(n)` usually takes a `nr` of bytes, and allocates memory.

`sub_100033ae` just forwards the call to new.

Comment: So it's basically something like `malloc`?

Comment: @AcidShout It's basically the C++ version of malloc in that it gives you a pointer to at least x bytes of consecutive  memory. There are some differences though, operator new can throw exceptions and cause new handlers to be called. There could also be a difference between what sort of meta data is stored about the allocated memory between malloc and new. They're different functions so it's best to treat them as such. After allocation you usually have object construction into the allocated memory.

Comment: @PeterAndersson thanks, really good explanation. This can be considered solved!